# post method is not displaying in my browser

Tags: express, form-data

//this is the code i took from tutorialspoint expressjs tutorials
the get variable is working but when using POST method, there is error "cannot get"

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer(); 
var app = express();


app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('views'));

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));     
app.use(upload.array()); // for parsing multipart/form-data

app.listen(3000);

app.post('/', function(req, res){
console.log(req.body);
res.send("recieved your request!");
});
```

i created the form.pug file in views folder

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error, remove

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

**Update**

When you enter a url in the browser, it does a get request. You don't server any get requests for your app.

Post is only used when you want to add more data, not when you want to get some. Try to add the following code:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("served your request!");
});
```

And use a rest client like Postman to do a post request to / to get the other message